# Is there a way to pow 2 BigInteger Numbers in java?

Tags: java, biginteger

I have to pow a bigInteger number with another BigInteger number.

Unfortunately, only one BigInteger.pow(int) is allowed.

I have no clue on how I can solve this problem.

Comment: I know this is not the point, but what are you doing that raising a number to a normal `int` exponent would not achieve? In other words, are you positive that you can't simply use the exponent's `intValue` method and call it a day?

Comment: The simple solution would be using a for loop (multiply the first number by itself as many times as the second number says). Given that would be terribly slow for large values of y, I'm not sure this is even reasonably possible.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Well I gotta pow a 2048 bit long hex number. Afai understood it. I need to use  a bigger datatype than int, in order to store that number.

Comment: @NintyNinerQuery yes, but to the power of what? It's the exponent that needs to fit an `int`, not your 2048-bit number, right?

Comment: What I mean is: do you really need an **exponent** that's larger than `2^31`?

Comment: @NintyNinerQuery Do you want to use `modPow()` instead? Most likely you want to use modulo afterwards anyway.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca

The exponent is quite literally a 2048 bit hex number :(. 

2^2048bit long hex number

Comment: @Progman yeah that is true! After that I want to mod. it with a prime number.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Sorry for causing confusion. I have some random given basis hex number g and a 2048 bit long (static) hex number. 

I need to exponent the 2048bit long hex number with g. 
Which means that I need to calculate g^2048bit long hex number.

Comment: There's (give or take)10^80 atoms in the universe. 80 is what, a 7 bit number? And you're asking how to raise a number to a 2048-bit number... This almost certainly an XY problem. Remember the guy that wanted to double the grains of rice on each square on a chess board as his reward? He was executed, and that's just 2^64.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have to pow a bigInteger number with another BigInteger number.

No, you don't.

You read a crypto spec and it seemed to say that. But that's not what it said; you didn't read carefully enough. The mathematical 'universe' that the math in the paper / spec you're reading operates in is different from normal math. It's a modulo-space. All operations are implicitly performed modulo X, where X is some number the crypto algorithm explains.

You can do that [just fine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,java.math.BigInteger)).

Alternatively, the spec is quite clear and says something like: `C = (A^B) % M` and you've broken that down in steps (... first, I must calculate A to the power of B. I'll worry about what the % M part is all about later). That's not how that works - you can't lop that operation into parts. `(A^B) % M` is quite doable, and has its own efficient algorithm. `(A^B)` is simply not calculable without a few years worth of the planet's entire energy and GDP output.

The reason I know that must be what you've been reading, is because `(A ^ B) % M` is a common operation in crypto. (Well, that, and the simple fact that A^B can't be done).

Just to be crystal clear: When I say impossible, I mean it in the same way 'travelling faster than the speed of light' is impossible. It's a law in the physics sense of the word: If you really just want to do A^B and not in a modspace where B is so large it doesn't fit in an int, a computer cannot calculate it, and the result will be gigabytes large. int can hold about 9 digits worth. Just for fun, imagine doing X^Y where both X and Y are 20 digit numbers.

The result would have 10^21 digits.

That's roughly equal to the total amount of disk space available worldwide. 10^12 is a terabyte. You're asking to calculate a number where, forget about calculating it, merely **storing** it requires one thousand million harddisks each of 1TB.

Thus, I'm 100% certain that you do not want what you think you want.

TIP: If you can't follow the math (which is quite bizarre; it's not like you get modulo-space math in your basic AP math class!), generally rolling your own implementation of a crypto algorithm isn't going to work out. The problem with crypto is, if you mess up, often a unit test cannot catch it. No; someone will hack your stuff and then you know, and that's a high price to pay. Rely on experts to build the algorithm, spend your time ensuring the protocol is correct (which is still quite difficult to get right, don't take that lightly!). If you insist, make dang sure you have a heap of plaintext+keys / encrypted (or plaintext / hashed, or whatever it is you're doing) pairs to test against, and assume that whatever you wrote, even if it passes those tests, is still insecure because e.g. it is trivial to leak the key out of your algorithm using timing attacks.

Answer (score 3):

Since you anyway want to use it in a modulo operation with a prime number, like @Progman said in the comments, you can use `modPow()`

Below is an example code:

```
        // Create BigInteger objects
        BigInteger biginteger1, biginteger2, exponent, result;
  
        //prime number
        int pNumber = 5;
        // Intializing all BigInteger Objects
        biginteger1 = new BigInteger("23895");
        biginteger2 = BigInteger.valueOf(pNumber);
        exponent = new BigInteger("15");
  
        // Perform modPow operation on the objects and exponent
        result = biginteger1.modPow(exponent, biginteger2);
```

Comment: Thanks :)! I appreciate it a lot!